# How do I improve my Largest Content Paint when all that remains to be improved are optimized CSS files?

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I'm optimizing my website and attempting to enhance the Largest Contentful Paint, but the only item that appears to require work are the optimised CSS files made with [W3Speedster](https://w3speedster.com/); here is a link to [the Google speed test I performed](https://pagespeed.web.dev/report?url=https%3A%2F%2Fglobalhelpswap.com%2Fwhale-watching-uk%2F&form_factor=mobile). I want the LCP to be less than 2.5.

**Any advice would be greatly welcomed; thank you!**

Answer (score 0):

That does not mean it takes over 3 seconds to render the content.
The rendering of you page from start render to document complete is only about 0.100 seconds.

You server is your biggest problem.  It's slow.
The best thing you could do for your pages is either eliminate shareaholic.js, or get it to load sooner.  It appears there may be some sort of lazyload.  I does not load until 1.8 seconds.  That is likely the reason the page rendering starts too late.  That and too many font and CSS files.  The Browser cannot begin rendering and till it has all the CSS and font files.  shareaholic.js is your 15th file being loaded. There are 5 images being prefetched before this js. 
You need to get the page to start rendering sooner.  You could join some of the CSS files together to reduce the number of files being retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

It's just your ads. :)
You'll most likely not be able to make it any faster. Maybe a little bit. I reduced it from 4 seconds on Cloudways Nginx servers to under 2 seconds on WPX Apache servers.

The problem is, when your ads are loading in the beginning a bidding war takes place. It's only after this they can load in the ads. So it'll always take time.

If I were you, I'd change the host to something like WPX, they will also help you make it as optimized as possible, with ads. If not changing the host, I'd focus on the CLS. Much bigger factor and easier to do something about.